# Could I set Axis in String but not the default double, and set the small pixel width and color in JHeatChart, like the chart below

Tags: java

I want generate a chart like this, now I try use JHeatChart, but the Axis is double and there is no method to set the width and Color of small pixel in Image.

Comment: show us chart and code?

Comment: sorry, i am a new comer, and i have not the rights to insert my image in my question, i am trying ....

Comment: I want to generate a heat map using Jheatchart, and i want show 2016-10-20 in Axis, not the double value 10.0 provide in default, how can i set this, i can not find the method in the document JheatChart provided. Thanks so much!

Comment: different weight show different color , like many small pixel in image, how can I set this small pixel's border width and border color, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by used JheatChart method `setYValues(java.lang.Object[] yValues)`,this method can transfer a `String[]`to my Axis, thanks to everyone!